# "Difference between "Verify" and "Ensure" In Software Test Case Writing?

Tags: testing

While writing a test case, what should come under "Expected Result" field. what is the meaning of "Ensure that userID is 1" and "Verify" that userID is 1".

Answer (score 0):

well, writing any testcase you should remember some features:
Any test case contains following:

- ID
- functionality which it associated to (e.g. 'navigation menu')
- short description (or title)
- full description (with detailed instructions what is supposed to be
  checked)
- expected result (proper behaviour of the system in accordance with
  documentation and specifications)
- actual result: failed, passed, passed with restrictions, N/A with
  reason (not implemented, faced with blocking issue)
- comments

So expected result stands for propert behaviour of the system which is taken from documentation and from the specification to the software product. If you come across with a kinda of ambiguity, you should consult to BA(business analyst or any other person who is responsible for the writing documentation to the product).
'Ensure that userID is 1' and 'Verify that userID is 1' are the synonyms with the same underlying. **Ensure**, **verify**, **check that**, **make sure** are considered to be the synonms and equally can be used in point 4:  full description (with detailed instructions what is supposed to be
   checked).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Both are similar. Doesn't matter, as long as you you get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Verify and Ensure are not exactly the same when it comes to the action taken in response.  To verify something, you generally have to check that it is true and indicate it in the documentation.  If you ensure something, you generally check that it is true and make a determination as to how to proceed.  If asked to verify a chemical used is not expired, you indicate it is not on the record; if asked to ensure the chemical used is not expired, you must be sure it is useable in order to proceed.